# How to dispose Entity Framework record objects after insertion?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, garbage-collection, idisposable

I insert a lot of records into an Entity Framework database and don't need them any more after I run `.SaveChanges();`. Moreover, I actually would like the memory to be released as soon as possible (for new records to be created). I don't keep any variables linking to old records objects but the GC doesn't seem to delete them, so, I think, it is the data context or something else who keeps them alive. How do I dispose them correctly to let GC to free memory they occupy?

Comment: is your context in a `using` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SaveChanges()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx) does not release the resources, it just commits the changes to the database.

To release the resources you need to call [`Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738763.aspx) method of the object context.
It can be done explicitly by [calling `.Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) method or by putting your code inside the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

```
using(var ctx = new EntityModel())
{
    // do the inserts
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Also, [`ObjectContext.Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738763.aspx) method [closes the connection if it was opened by the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx), otherwise you can run out of the connections...

Here is a similar question: [Should Entity Framework Context be Put into Using Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824330/should-entity-framework-context-be-put-into-using-statement)

Answer (score 3):

1. This isn't really a problem. Let the GC do its work.
2. *I think, it is the data context or something else who keeps them alive.*

Correct. The basic solution is to Dispose the Context as soon and as often as possible.

Comment: Well, but I am going to use it again right after. I have to insert millions of records sequentially, do you mean I have to dispose and re-create the database connection that many times? Can't the context be forced to forget about the records inserted?

Comment: Disposing a Context is not the same as closing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the context in a 'using' statement?

```
using(var context = new MyContext())
{
    // Do work here .....
}
```