# Extract DbContext into instance field within WCF service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, iis, testing

I'm new in the field of WCF services and Entity Framework 6, that's why a very fundamental question came up to me. I have a WCF service providing data from a SQL Server database via Entity Framework 6. For this, there are several operations defined within the service. The service is hosted within IIS.
Due to several tutorials and blogs, I followed the pattern of creating an instance of my `DbContext` per operation within an `using`-statement. So it looks more or less like this:

```
public class MyService
{
    public List<HouseDto> GetHouses()
    {
        var houseDtos = new List<HouseDto>();

        using (var context = new TestDbContext())
        {
            var houses = context.Houses.ToList();
            foreach (var house in houses)
            {
                var houseDto = house.ToDto();
                houseDtos.Add(houseDto);
            }
        }    

        return houseDtos;
    }

    public List<StreetDto> GetStreets()
    {
        var streetDtos = new List<StreetDto>();

        using (var context = new TestDbContext())
        {
            var streets = context.Streets.ToList();
            foreach (var street in streets)
            {
                var streetDto = street.ToDto();
                streetDtos.Add(streetDto);
            }
        }    

        return streetDtos;
    }
}
```

Now I want to test the service operation `GetHouses()`. For this, I refactored the class in the way of having a `TestDbContext` as an instance field:

```
public class MyService
{
    private TestDbContext context;

    public MyService()
    {
        context = new TestDbContext();
    }

    internal MyService(TestDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public List<HouseDto> GetHouses()
    {
        var houseDtos = new List<HouseDto>();

        var houses = context.Houses.ToList();
        foreach (var house in houses)
        {
            var houseDto = house.ToDto();
            houseDtos.Add(houseDto);
        }    

        return houseDtos;
    }

    public List<StreetDto> GetStreets()
    {
        var streetDtos = new List<StreetDto>();

        var streets = context.Streets.ToList();
        foreach (var street in streets)
        {
            var streetDto = street.ToDto();
            streetDtos.Add(streetDto);
        }

        return streetDtos;
    }
}
```

This enabled me to inject a mocked `TestDbContext` and test the whole service operation, not only the DTO creation method `ToDto()`.

Now several questions came up to me:

1. Are there several independent instances of `MyService` within IIS or does IIS create and hold exactly one instance of `MyService` (some kind of singleton)?
2. If there is one instance kept alive: does the underlying database connection of `TestDbContext` in my refactored class (`TestDbContext` as instance field) ever get closed or will it remain open until GC/the service within IIS stops?
3. If there are several instances: does each web request to `MyService` imply the creation of a new instance of `TestDbContext` or is there a more sophisticated logic?

All of these points can be summarized into one essential question: is my refactoring save for production (read AND write) or could I encounter weird phenomena and avoid this pattern?

Especially the two following posts made me feel that my approach could be safe:

- [Microsoft testing sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx) --> why should they create such an example if it is not appropriate for productive use?
- [Should Entity Framework Context be Put into Using Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824330/should-entity-framework-context-be-put-into-using-statement/19846918#19846918) --> even without the using statement, the database connection seems to get closed, but by whom?

I'm very interested in your answers!

PS: Please don't pay too much attention on the code, it is just a sample. Within my production code, the operations are more complex. The question is definitely more related to the underlying "magic", what's is going on behind the scenes, etc.

Comment: Any ideas about this? At least presumptions?

Answer (score 0):

Within another forum, we've found an alternative way of combining both (testable and safe code). Here is my solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/69705868-3c86-4fa6-b5c5-7b79e67ce283/#d777ff90-af9a-474a-b9b0-fbf46f799174